# llvm: input and output values from a loop

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, llvm

I am trying to obtain the input and output values of a loop by using `findInputsOutputs()` as shown in the code below:

```
DominatorTree &DT = getAnalysis<DominatorTreeWrapperPass>().getDomTree();
CodeExtractor Extractor(DT, *L);
Extractor.findInputsOutputs(inputs, outputs);
```

When I print the input and output values for the following test code:

```
void aFunc(void)
{
    int sum=0;
    puts("aFunc()");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int fact=i*2;
        sum=sum+i+fact;
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
}
```

I get the following:

```
Inputs
type i32*      name i
type i32*      name fact
type i32*      name sum

Outputs
```

However, I was expecting the output to be:

```
Inputs
type i32*      name sum

Outputs
type i32*      name sum
```

Because, to my understanding, `i` and `fact` are declared inside the loop, hence they are neither input nor output. Secondly, `sum` is being used outside the loop, hence should appear in outputs.

Am I right?